# Test for duplicates in a Mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

so I have a simple newsletter signup form. I can add users into the database, but I want to account for duplicate emails. This is what I have right now.

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email'");


  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


  if($num_rows){
    echo "You've already registered! Thanks anyway";
  }

  else{

  mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO Users (Name, Email) VALUES('$name' , '$email')");
  echo "Thanks for signing up, $name.";
  }
```

When I click submit, it will add it to the database, regardless if the email is the same.

The mysql_query that gets $result is fine. However, for some reason the if statement doesn't get called. Any idea why?

Comment: That's because you're mixing MySQL APIs so your second query which will always be executed, plus this `if($num_rows)` should be `if($num_rows >0)`

Comment: Might be better to enforce this on the DB side. Make email unique in the table.

Answer (score 3):

> *"The mysql_query that gets $result is fine"*

Your DB connection sounds to be `mysql_` - and you're using `mysqli_` functions below that.

Use `mysqli_` exclusively and do not mix them, *they don't.*

---

***Sidenote:*** Your question is confusing.

You state: *When I click submit, it will add it to the database, regardless if the email is the same.* - then you say *The `mysql_query` that gets `$result` is fine.*

---

This: `if($num_rows)` should be `if($num_rows >0)`

Use this for your DB connection:

```
$db_connection = mysqli_connect("your_host","user","password","your_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

then do:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email'");

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows >0){
echo "You've already registered! Thanks anyway";
exit;
}

else{

mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO Users (Name, Email) VALUES('$name' , '$email')");
echo "Thanks for signing up, $name.";
}
```

- **Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php** on your query.
- I.e.: `or die(mysqli_error($db_connection))`

---

**Warning**

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

***Footnotes:***

If you want to avoid duplicates, set your column(s) as [**UNIQUE**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm).